# How to read application configuration of previous version if current not exist

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration, appdata

The application configuration is usually stored here:

```
C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\[COMPANY]\[APPLICATION]_[HASH]\[VERSION]\user.config
```

So if there is a new version, there will be no configuration - the version number has increased.
**Q:** How can I load the configuration of the previous version in this case?

An alternative would be to write only one configuration file that is stored in a path with **no** version.  Is this possible?